# Update image links in database

Tags: images, database, urls

I recently changed the URL of a wordpress site and I can't seem to find some of the image links

I was able to update most of the links in the wp_posts tables

```
update wp_posts set guid = REPLACE(guid, 'domain.com/wp/', 'domain.com/blog/');
update wp_posts set post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'domain.com/wp', 'domain.com/blog');
```

Are there other tables, columns that I am missing?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I re-ran the following update and now my links work!

```
update wp_posts set post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'http://domain.com/wp', 'http://domain.com/blog');
```